# How to avoid converting latex in pandoc markdown to markdown conversion

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I want to use pandoc to add citations to my markdown-latex file to post it on a website

```
Citation of [@gao2022scalingRMOver]
\begin{equation*}
    1 = 2+2
\end{equation*}

# References
```

Currently with `pandoc --citeproc --bibliography references.bib -o out.md -t markdown-citations test.md`

```
Citation of (Gao, Schulman, and Hilton 2022) `\begin{equation*}
    1 = 2+2
\end{equation*}`{=tex}

# References {#references .unnumbered}

::: {#refs .references .csl-bib-body .hanging-indent entry-spacing="0"}
::: {#ref-gao2022scalingRMOver .csl-entry}
Gao, Leo, John Schulman, and Jacob Hilton. 2022. "Scaling Laws for
Reward Model Overoptimization." <https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10760>.
:::
:::
```

Is there a way to avoid generating the "`" and "{=tex} ? It breaks the online converter used by lesswrong.com